# Django; How to insert the spaces between the output of the form data in the browser?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How can I insert spaces in form data?

For example, when I submit this data,

[image]

it outputs like this.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: you can use django-ckeditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the built in [linebreaksbr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) template tag to accomplish this.

Comment: or https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks if that fits the requirment better.

Comment: Good! I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [custome template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/), check the documentation on how to set it up:

In file `foo_extras.py`:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='add_br')
def add_br(value, autoescape=True):
    return mark_safe(value.replace('\n', '<br>' ))
```

And in your html:

```
{% load bar_extras %}

{% for foo in foos %}
<h1>{{ foo.comment|add_br }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```